# Compare Python Web Frameworks and their respective HTML5 APIs Implementations

Tags: python, django, web-applications, html, tornado

If you are familiar with a specific python web framework that has implementations for HTML5 API(s) ie.WebSockets, Forms, WebWorkers, WebStorage, Communication, Geolocation, Canvas, etc.

Then please list the name of the framework and its HTML5 capabilities.

Comment: The technologies that you mention are mostly Javascript, not Python.

Comment: http://github.com/finiteloop/tornado/blob/master/tornado/websocket.py

Comment: Every major web framework have libraries that helps in web development. Tornado have a HTML5 websocket implementation. Do you mean by javascript that I can for example use JQuery for this sort of thing??

Comment: "...mostly Javascript, not Python." That said, some web frameworks do play nicer with some JS than others. Django, however, is fairly agnostic on these matters (although the admin makes use of jquery). Part of the problem is that many of the HTML5 features don't have standard implementations and it seems that the developing community at Django is very deliberate when it comes to adding new features. tl;dr: There may be a python framework that offers specific support of HTML5 features. I don't know of any, and for at least 6 months to a year you'll have to roll your own if you're using Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer writing your client code in Python, check out [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/).

I'm sorry, I haven't looked into its HTML5 capabilities.